# lit-element not changing view after property value change

Tags: typescript, lit-element, deno, lit-html

some code removed for brevity...

basic simple element

```
@customElement("simple-el")
export class SimpleEl extends LitElement {
  @property() user = "joe";

  render() {
    return html`<p>Hello, ${this.user}!</p>`;
  }
}
```

calling element

```
import "./scratch.ts";

@customElement("doos-main")
export class Doos extends LitElement {
 
  @property() selName = "JOHN";


  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  render() {
    return html`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bulma.min.css" />
      <doos-nav token="${this.token}"></doos-nav>
      <simple-el user="${this.selName}"></simple-el>

      //this displays a button and calls _buttonClick correctly
      ${this.renderView(this.view)} 

      <doos-footer name="FOOTER"></doos-footer>`;
  }


  _buttonClick(e: Event) {
    console.log(e);
    this.selName = "CHANGED!";
  }

}
```

when i click the button, i change the property value of `selName` and my thinking is that `SimpleElement.user`  is bound to `selName`. so changing `selName` should display the view to `Hello CHANGED!!`

However this is not working.  I am getting the original set though: `Hello JOHN!`

i have tried calling `async/await this.requestUpdate();` as well

is my thinking wrong and/or implementation?

EDIT:
I probably should add that I'm using deno's bundling command to build my JS.

*deno bundle --unstable --watch -c ./tsconfig.json ./mod.ts ./mod.js*

here is the tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "deno.ns"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks ok I think. Did you make sure that `this` references `Doos` within `_buttonClick `?

Comment: its inside the class definition , so i think i got the right scope here, but maybe i can spend some time verifying

Comment: Can you console log `this` in `_buttonClick` to ensure that the binding is correct? If not, can you share your implementation of `this.renderView(this.view)` so it will be easier to catch where you might be running into an issue?

Separately, what are you using to compile your decorators? I know sometimes babel drops the ball on this and doesn't associate the update flow correctly.

Comment: you need to use `this.requestUpdate` after property changes. see this https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com/2020/01/19/how-to-re-render-dom-on-value-change-in-lit-html/

Answer (score 1):

Properties are not the same as attributes, and they are only two-way reflected if you set reflected to true for those lit properties. This may be why a change to `selName` is not getting you a re-render of simple-el with an updated `user` property, because you only changed the attribute part of it.

```
<simple-el user="${this.selName}"></simple-el>
```

Should be using lit property binding

```
<simple-el .user="${this.selName}"></simple-el>
```

https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#bind-properties-to-templated-elements

Comment: yes you are correct, however this didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

A bit of important information is left out.  How is the call for `_buttonClick` setup.  More than likely this is not bound to the class object.  `this` in javascript can be reassigned and can be a bit unexpected coming from another language.

```
class Person {
  phrase = "Hello There!"

  speak(){
    console.log(this.phrase)
  }
}

const person = new Person();

person.speak(); // This returns "Hello There!"

const speak = person.speak;

speak(); // this gives you `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'phrase' of undefined`
```

This can be fixed a couple ways.

- Making sure the event callback it set up using arrow syntax `(e) => _buttonClick(e)`
- Using bind to make sure this is pointing to the class `_buttonClick.bind(this)`

```js
class Person2 {
  phrase = "Hello There!";

  constructor(){
    this.speak = this.speak.bind(this)
  }

  speak(){
    console.log(this.phrase)
  }
}

const person2 = new Person2();

const speak2 = person2.speak;

speak(); // This returns "Hello There!"
```

Comment: i changed _buttonClick to this:
`  _buttonClick = (e: Event) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.selName = "CHANGED!";
    console.log(this.selName);
  };`  with no luck

also did this after reverting the function back:  `this._buttonClick.bind(this);`  in the constructor it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ekuinc).

This might not working properly.

```
//this displays a button and calls _buttonClick correctly
  ${this.renderView(this.view)}
```

Or the problem can be related to

```
deno bundle --unstable --watch -c ./tsconfig.json ./mod.ts ./mod.js
```